# LINQ to SQL lambda exp. OrderBy, Case When,Dynamic Where

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, case

I'm using LINQ to SQL and LINQ dynamic where and order by.

I want to convert the code below(ASP) to C#.net.

```
    function getTestimonialList(statusCd)
     sWhere = ""
     if statusCd <> "" then
    sWhere = " where status='" & statusCd & "'"
     end if
     sqlStr="select * from testimonial" & sWhere & " order by case when status = 'P' then 1 when status = 'A' then 2 else 3 end, dateadded desc"
     set rs=getResult(sqlStr)
     set getTestimonialList=rs
end function
```

Here is my query :

```
var TestimonialList = from p in MainModelDB.Testimonials
                                  where String.IsNullOrEmpty(statusCd)?"1=1":p.status== statusCd
                              orderby p.status == 'P' ? 1 : (p.status == 'A' ? 2 : 3)
                              orderby p.DateAdded descending
                              select p;
```

the above example doesn't work! , any idea if its possible? any other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a query expression, I suggest you use the `Where`, `OrderBy` and `ThenByDescending` methods directly. For example:

```
IQueryable<Testimonial> testimonials = MainModelDB.Testimonials;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(statusCd))
{
    testimonials = testimonials.Where(t => t.status == statusCd);
}
var ordered = testimonials.OrderBy(t => t.status == 'P' ? 
                                           1 : (t.status == 'A' ? 2 : 3))
                          .ThenByDescending(t => t.DateAdded);
```

Note the use of `ThenByDescending` instead of `OrderByDescending` - your original query used two "primary" orderings which is almost never what you want.

I'm not entirely sure that the `OrderBy` clause will work, but it's worth a try. If it *doesn't* work, please say what happens instead of just saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: You sir! You are an epic guy who helped me to solve billions of problems. Thank you!
(`OrderBy` clause works just fine..)